# I am making an ajax call to load the contents into modal dialog; which seems to be working on all other browser than IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call to load the contents into modal dialog; which seems to be working on all other browser than Internet Explorer. In Internet Explorer it is freezing and I cannot do any thing I have to use Task Manager to end task. Can anyone tell me what can i do to resolve the freezing issue? The content that I am loading from the URL are dynamic HTML contents, which has scripts, etc.

```
try{
    var LOCALE ='en_us';
    var custNUm= 'Y0392287497';
    var dURL = 'https://www.over.com?cstNum='+custNUm+'&loc='+LOCALE;
    var mModal = $("<div class=\"mdialog\" role=\"dialog\"></div>").html('Loading Please Wait....').dialog({
            position : [ 'center', 20 ],
            modal : true,
            //autoOpen : false,
            bgiframe : true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape : false,
            title : "CUSTOMER MODAL",
            close : function(event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
    });

    $.ajax({
            url : dURL,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'text',
            timeout : 5000,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('html,body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            },
            success : function(textResponse) {               
                mcdpModal.html(textResponse);                      
            }
    });
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

Comment: https://www.over.com?cstNum=Y0392287497&loc=en_us

seems that data response coming from server is not valid..

http://jsfiddle.net/2HQKp/

Comment: the Response comming from the server has script tags which is loading the other js files; i am trying to inforce them to do a get call but it is making a post call i think which is doing the eval and freezing the IE.

Answer (score 0):

Want to the following: 1.Is ur Modal Window getting opened ?
 2.Is your data response comming from ur server
 3.Is this url u access resides in different domain ? (for 3 rd point:IE does not support Cross Domain AJAX Calls.You need to have both ur execution domain and the server domain to be same.)

Comment: Yes My Modal dilaog is getting opened and i am getting a resonse from the server; i can see the HTML that is comming from the server but in Ajax success call; when mcdpModal.html(textResponse);  is called it freezes the IE. i tried mcdpModal.load(url) also it does the same thing. They both are on the same domain.